# What is the point of matrix reduction in Branch & Bound problems?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, traveling-salesman, reduction, branch-and-bound

Pretty much as the title says.

This is done in branch & bound problems, specifically the travelling salesperson.

I understand how matrix reduction works, but I don't really get why you need to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't *need* to do it, but it makes the rest of the algorithm simpler and more efficient.

A branch-and-bound algorithm is a kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search) for an optimisation problem, where you don't have to explore the whole of every subtree before backtracking. Some subtrees (i.e. partial solutions) can be rejected when we know they can't lead to a better solution than the current best-solution-so-far.

It's useful to have a lower bound on how much any completion of a partial solution could cost. For example, if we have a path which goes from node A → B → C, then we know the path must leave node C, and at some points in the future it must leave nodes D, E and F (not necessarily in that order). If we know the minimum costs of leaving C, D, E and F then we can add those to the cost of our incomplete path, to get the minimum possible cost of a complete path starting with A → B → C. If that cost is higher than the cost of our best solution, then we can reject the partial solution A → B → C without exploring any further branches of it.

If we apply matrix reduction first, then the minimum cost of leaving every node will be zero, so we don't need to add anything to the current cost in order to compute that lower bound. The rule for rejecting A → B → C is simply whether the cost of that partial solution is higher than the cost of the best full solution so far. That simplifies the code and also saves the time it takes to do those additions.